# Regex with egrep to find lines consisting of file names <string>.<string>

Tags: regex, string, bash

I'm trying to search for all file names in this format: 
.

So essentially I want two non-empty strings consisting of ONLY english letters (a-z or A-Z) separated by a period.

Examples:

file.txt  (valid)

string.c  (valid)

file..txt (invalid - there are two periods)

al.       (invalid - need alpha string after period)

al. txt   (invalid - there is a space after the period)

---

I want to do this with egrep, but I'm having some trouble figuring this out

This is my expression so far, which I know will find lines that have more periods than I want:

```
 ".+\..+"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to grep filenames given by `find` or `ls`? Can you use a regex in find/ls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
egrep '^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for valid filenames within the current directory, you can combine find and egrep like this:

`ls | egrep '[a-zA-Z][\.][a-zA-Z]'`

or

`find . -type f | egrep '[a-zA-Z][\.][a-zA-Z]'`